# How to give a permissions of business units in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

suppose I have two business unit in marketing cloud Name as A and B .A can view All the subscribers but B can not view it . How can I achieve it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

In the Admin Tab:

- Click on the “Admin” Tab Click on “Business Units”
- Search for your Business Unit by typing parts of the name in the “Search”
- Press Search
- Choose your Business Unit
- Click Define Subscriber filter

  [image]

A prerequisite to this will be to create a Subscriber Profile Attribute from Subscribers > Profile Management.

You will need to set the Subcribers with the profile attribute in order to define which business unit / Subscriber Filter they shall apply to.

Comment: No problem - all up votes are welcomed and appreciated